# How to get the last field and pass it on?

Tags: bash, split, parameter-expansion

I've try next script

```
#!/bin/bash
VERSION="2.0.3.44"
BUILD_NUMBER=${VERSION##*.}
BUILD_QUERY="${BUILD_NUMBER}/foo/bar/"
```

Expected result:

```
44/foo/bar/
```

Actual result:

```
/foo/bar/
```

Has anyone come across this?

Comment: What OS are you on? I've just tried it on macOS X terminal and echo $BUILD_QUERY works perfectly fine

Comment: And post the SHELL you are using (`echo $SHELL `). Under Arch Linux with zsh this works also perfectly fine. `zsh --version`  -> `zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS. `bash --version` -> `GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`, `echo $SHELL` ->  `/bin/bash`

Comment: Works fine under `GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu).`.

Comment: Works fine with bash 4.2.53 and 4.3.30, too.

Comment: Check if the dot is there in your second line.

Comment: Try to replace `#!/bin/bash` with `#!/bin/bash --norc`.

Comment: If it still doesn't work, maybe you ought to paste the output from `xxd < the_script` here.